# Firebase auth - how to relogin the user?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am fairly new to firebase. While going through docs below are some questions that i came up with, to which i am not able to find any answer. So putting it here.

1. I am using firebase phone authentication to login. So after login, lets say the user relaunches the app. Then i am trying to re-authenticate the user using the available user-id/token or anything thats available from the first login. Does firebase has provision to re-authenticate using any available token? I am not able to find any. If this is not the way to approach this problem then what is the recommended approach?
   I don't want to redirect the user to login page to feed the phone no. and otp again.
2. Same kind of situation, when the user comes back online from offline. SHould i reauthenticate? If not then how the the already captured records will be processed? And the new records will be processed?

Comment: Such questions have already been asked by a lot of people, you'd have found them, if you had researched a bit. Please take care to look for such answers. You can use the example [here](https://medium.com/@nils.backe/firebase-authentication-in-flutter-4b7aa9627046) to get the currently logged in user. If it returns null that means, you need to ask them to login again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase automatically persists the user credentials, and restores them (asynchronously) when the app is restarted. You don't need to do anything for that. Just [listen for auth state changes](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage#authentication-state) to get notified when the user info is restored, or (in rare cases) when it failed to restore.

Comment: Thanks Frank. I have tried something similar. In the code right after initializing the firebase app, i am starting to listen to the three streams - authStateChange, idTokenChnage and userChange. And not disposing the streams. But on restarting the app, none of the streams are emitting anything. I will try it again. But could it be because i am using phone no/otp as the user login method. I only have phone no./otp as the auth method.

Comment: Thanks Frank. I am getting the logged in user after app restart using above solution. I don't know what i was doing differently that i was not getting the user. I am also checking some other scenarios like switching between offline/online usng flutter firebase. I will raise the questions here. Or let me know if there is any better platform.

Comment: Good to hear you got it working @Braj    If you have trouble going forward, indeed post another question with the [minimal code with which we can reproduce that problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to increase the chances that someone can help and decrease the chances of downvotes.